# Crear un while que abarque la misma condicion de 8 objeto de una clase

Tags: java

Buenas no se si es posible.
Tengo una clase carrera y tiene 8 objetos atleta y un int meta.
Necesito un while qeu es mientras atleta.getDistancia< meta pues sigue corriendo
la cosa es tener un while generico que me valga para los 8 a la vez y no ir poninedo uno por uno atleta1.getdistancia

```
public class Pista {

    private Atleta a1;
    private Atleta a2;
    private Atleta a3;
    private Atleta a4;
    private Atleta a5;
    private Atleta a6;
    private Atleta a7;
    private Atleta a8;
    private int meta;

    public Pista(Atleta a1, Atleta a2, Atleta a3, Atleta a4, Atleta a5, Atleta a6, Atleta a7, Atleta a8, int meta) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
        this.a4 = a4;
        this.a5 = a5;
        this.a6 = a6;
        this.a7 = a7;
        this.a8 = a8;
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public void empezarCarrera() {

        a1.start();
        a2.start();
        a3.start();
        a4.start();
        a5.start();
        a6.start();
        a7.start();
        a8.start();

        while (a1.getDistanciaRecorrida() < meta || a2.getDistanciaRecorrida() < meta || a3.getDistanciaRecorrida()<meta) {


        }
```

eso es lo que llevo de codigo

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear una función que recibiera la lista de la distancia recorrida por cada atleta y devolviera la máxima distancia recorrida en la lista. Luego, sólo tendrías que pasarle esa distancia máxima a la condición del bucle while.

O integrarlo en la función que ya tienes, así:

```
public class Pista {

private Atleta a1;
private Atleta a2;
private Atleta a3;
private Atleta a4;
private Atleta a5;
private Atleta a6;
private Atleta a7;
private Atleta a8;
private int meta;

public Pista(Atleta a1, Atleta a2, Atleta a3, Atleta a4, Atleta a5, Atleta a6, Atleta a7, Atleta a8, int meta) {
    this.a1 = a1;
    this.a2 = a2;
    this.a3 = a3;
    this.a4 = a4;
    this.a5 = a5;
    this.a6 = a6;
    this.a7 = a7;
    this.a8 = a8;
    this.meta = meta;
}

public void empezarCarrera() {

    Atleta[] atletas = new Atletas[8];
    atletas = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8};
    int maxDistancia = atletas[0].getDistanciaRecorrida();
    for (int = 0; i < atletas. length(); i++) {
        atletas[i].start();
    }

    for (int = 1; i < atletas. length(); i++) {
        if (atletas[i]. getDistanciaRecorrida > maxDistancia) {
            maxDistancia = atletas[i]. getDistanciaRecorrida;
        {
    }

    while (maxDistancia < meta) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías trabajar con colecciones (List, por ejemplo) o arrays, por ejemplo:

```
public class Pista {

    private Atleta [] atletas;

    private int meta;

    public Pista(Atleta [] atletas, int meta) {
        this.atletas = atletas;

        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public void empezarCarrera() {

        for (int i=0; i< this.atletas.length; i++) {
            this.atletas[i].start();
        }

       while (!this.algunoTermina()) {
         ...
       }
    }

    private boolean algunoTermina() {
        for (int i=0; i< this.atletas.length; i++) {
            if (this.atletas[i].distanciaRecorrida > this.meta) {
               return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Esto te da además flexibilidad, porque puedes trabajar con pistas de 4, 6, 8 o 9 calles sin tener que tocar el código de `Pista`.

Comment: el problema es que es un trabajo con hilos si no usaria list

Comment: No entiendo el problema con los hilos y las listas, ¿a qué te refieres?